# 2001 Toyota Celica starting problem

Tags: toyota, starting, manual-transmission, starter, celica

Car is a manual with 240000kms on the clock.

Car is hesitant to start sometimes. I think these videos will be helpful for someone to diagnose the problem. Is it a failing starter? or something else?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gHn8V0c845uyzodS6nZf5Cb4sK2NAkpD/view

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zcZa9ofUPfCqkft2Dd14awYfAWE__JlG/view

Few days ago it didn't start at all (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ismyNAuNYU-G7d8STRYzN4BnHIUcCGnz/view) but then when tried again in the afternoon it started back again (although still bit hesitant).

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question to hep someone come across this thread in future, it was the starter motor.

Comment: Glad you solved it. In my experience, if the starter motor is beginning to die, it will sound like it is working *slower* for a few days leading up to when it completely dies.